# Firefox only shows a black window over RDP

Tags: firefox, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 desktop running Firefox 4.  If I remote-desktop (RDP) from another PC into my already-running session, the Firefox window turns black.  Flash applications are still visible, if I'm on a tab with one, and I can apparently interact with Firefox normally, I just can't see anything in the window.  I'm after an explanation, if possible, and (even better!) a workaround or fix that doesn't involve a different web browser :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 4 has changed over to use hardware rendering to improve performance and it is probably this change that is breaking your view of Firefox over RDP.

There is a page at http://www.trishtech.com/internet/disable_hardware_acceleration_in_firefox_4.php that tells you how to disable the hardware acceleration, so it may be worth giving that a try first.

You may well have to close and reopen Firefox for the change to take effect.